# PHP writing to a file from an output stream only writes the first few lines

Tags: php, bash, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to write to a file (file.txt) from an output stream from a remote server. The output stream's content is generated from a bash/expect script on a remote server. I am not sure how `fwrite()` works, however, when I echo the `fget()` I can see the whole output from the script.

Does anyone know if `fwrite()` only writes the first few lines of the output stream? Or when does it stop writing? I have tried using a while loop to get it to continuously to write but I only see the first few lines in my file.txt `while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {fwrite($fopenText, $line);}` . However, when I echo the `fget()` I can see the whole output stream on the webpage I need the full output to be written to my file.txt, which is not doing.

How can I accomplish this?

```
$gwUser = 'user';
$gwPwd = 'pwd';
$pathToScript1 = '/home/user/up.sh';
$pathToScript2 = '/home/user/down.sh';

if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $gwUser, $gwPwd);            
    if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $pathToScript1);
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
        $stream_err = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);

        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/my/path/file.txt";
        touch($path);
        chmod($path, 0777);
        $fopenText = fopen($path, "w");
        while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {fwrite($fopenText, $line);} //this doesn't give me the full output stream
        echo '<pre>' . "------------------------\n" . '</pre>';
        while($line = fgets($stream_err)) {flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
        fclose($stream);
        fclose($fopenText);
    }

    //I can get the the output stream this way, but this is not what i want.
    if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 

        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "$pathToScript2");
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
        $stream_err = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
        while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
        echo '<pre>' . "------------------------\n" . '</pre>';
        while($line = fgets($stream_err)) {flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
        fclose($stream);                
    }
}
```

file.txt output:

```
[root@psat main]# cat file.txt
cd /home/user/
My current directory is:/home/user
./myExpectScript.sh
```

expected file.txt output (what i get back from `$_POST['option'] == 2` echo):

```
cd /home/user/
My current directory is:/home/user/
./myExpectScript.sh
spawn /bin/bash
[user@gateway user]$ spawn /bin/bash
[user@gateway user]$ ./hexMsg -o 3 20000 0 0 0
??
[user@gateway user]$ /usr/local/bin/ssh " @ "
...
...
(omitted for simplicity)
```

Comment: `$_POST['option'] == 1` is using `$pathToScript1` while `$_POST['option'] == 2` is using `$pathToScript2` so they are running different shell scripts. Are you sure the output should be the same?

Comment: @neuromatter Sorry for the confusion, the output doesn't matter, I got this part working, cause even if I call the same script it the `fwrite` file.txt only shows the first few lines, while my `option == 2` will echo what I need.  I am just trying to get the stream to fully write to file.txt this is where I am having problems. Let's just say both scripts do that same thing for now.

Comment: Are you seeing the `-----` line? If not, the SSH connection may not be exiting, so the `fwrite()` loop hasn't finished.

Comment: BTW, in HTML you should use `<hr>` to draw a line, not `-----`.

Comment: @Barmar I only see the `-----` line when use the `$_POST['option'] == 2` way. Whenever I use the `fwrite()` none of my echos show on the page. Does `fwrite()` buffer it differently than regular echos? How could I trouble shoot this?

Comment: You have `flush()` in your regular echoes, so that flushes the buffers. You're not doing that in the `fwrite()` loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the SSH connection hasn't returned, so the `fwrite()` loop hasn't finished and the file isn't closed. As a result, some of the output may be buffered. Try flushing the buffer after each write:

```
    while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {
        fwrite($fopenText, $line);
        fflush($fopenText);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... That didn't work.. I am still only seeing the first three lines in my `file.txt` I am going to wait longer to see if it shows up in a bit. One thing to note that in my `$_POST['option'] == 2` it takes about 5 minutes before i see the full output (end of script), during the waiting time the page is blank... do you think this might be something in the back end server with buffer settings that needs to be set?

Comment: It might be. Try using the `pty` argument to `ssh2_exec()`. When terminal emulation is enabled, it should prevent buffering on the server.

Comment: It is working now... dumb mistake by me... apparently in my `$pathToScript1` I commented out the `cd /home/user/` and only had the `echo cd /home/user/` therefore it wasn't finding the directory. I am able to get the output now. I also tried it without the `fflush($fopenText);` and it still works. Thank you for your help though!